# Return unique nodes in Cypher path query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to retrieve a unique set of elements linked to a given graph node.  I have some nodes loaded into a Neo4j graph database, which are connected using a 'TO' relationship (e.g. node 6 connects 'TO' node 7). I have been able to retrieve all paths between my start node and others linked by the 'TO' relationship using:

```
    start a = node(6)
    match p = (a)-[r:TO*..]->(b)
    return distinct EXTRACT(n in nodes(p): n);
```

This gives me output paths that are distinct, but still have duplicate node values, e.g.:

```
    +-------------------------------------------------------+
    | p                                                     |
    +-------------------------------------------------------+
    | [Node[6]{},:TO[5] {},Node[7]{}]                       |
    | [Node[6]{},:TO[5] {},Node[7]{},:TO[9] {},Node[11]{}]  | 
    etc...
```

**How can I combine these paths into a single list containing unique path values?**  I have tried using COLLECT but this just results in a nested version of the above results:

```
    start a = node(6) 
    match p = (a)-[r:TO*..]->(b) 
    return collect(distinct p);

    [[Node[6]{},:TO[5] {},Node[7]{}],[Node[6]{},:TO[5] {},Node[7]{},:TO[9] {}, ... ]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm confused about exactly the result you want (can you give an example if this isn't right?). Do you want paths or do you want nodes? If you want nodes, then maybe you just want:

```
start a = node(6)
match (a)-[:TO*]->(b)
return collect(distinct b);
```

Comment: I'm looking for all the nodes in all the paths.  Basically all nodes that are connected to 'a'.  The problem I'm having is removing the duplicate nodes, since the same node may appear in several paths.  It looks like your code will return a distinct set of end nodes for all paths.

Comment: It will return a distinct set of all nodes connected to a. Because at some point, they will all be end nodes.

Comment: Try it, I think it might be what you want.

Comment: Wes you are right. This works perfectly!  I couldn't test the code before b/c I was on my phone...sorry for doubting you! haha.